# Primefaces - Insert a text on the cursor position inside <p:inputText>

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, primefaces

I need to insert a text on the cursor position of the `<p:inputText>` .

I use this line on a javascript function:

```
let textToInsert = 'hello';
PF(wvarObjet).jq.insertText(PF(wvarObjet).jq.getSelection().start, textToInsert, '', false);
```

But this will actually insert the cursor position number (for example : 5) in the beginning of the  `<p:inputText>` field..

Comment: Can you insert bold text in an inputText?